# How to add and update npm packages for a new Angular app in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, visual-studio-2019

I just installed and created my first Angular app in Visual Studio 2019. I used the .Net Core Web Application type project and the Angular framework.
I see in the package.json file, Angular 6.1.10 is being used. I know I can install packages using the cli, but how do I install new packages (ex. Angular 7 or Angular Material), from/within the Visual Studio UI and update old packages to  newer versions?

I'd like to try and stay within the VS 2019 UI!

Is this even possible in the VS UI?

Answer (score 4):

As you want to try and stay within the VS 2019 UI!

```
Open VS 2019 --> From right side, click on 'Open a local folder'(Of course you can use alternative ways too) --> Navigate to ClientApp or Whatever your folder name where package.json exists.

Then, `Tools --> NuGet Package Manager --> Package Manager Console`
```

As you specified "I know I can install packages using the cli", use your required commands. For commands, see @Mahi's answer.

In this way, you dont need to come out from VS 2019.

Comment: One of the other ways is using the menu item: View -> Other Windows -> Package Manager Console. Then do "cd ClientApp". You of course still need to know how to use the npm commands. There is no UI for that.

Answer (score 3):

As Sajeetharan, mentioned there is no separate support from VS2019.

## Try this:-

```
1) npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
2) npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
3) npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
```

and,

## Update old packages to new packages:-

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

There is NO support in terms of UI support in Visual studio 2019 and i would say it is not needed as well.

You can always go and add the necessary packages needed and do a **`npm i`**. I personally  open the ClientApp folder in VSCODE which makes development easier for Angular